# My symbolicated crash report looks like not symbolicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

My users are saying my app is crashing on iPhone 5. I tested it on simulator but there was no problem. But i am getting weird crash reports from iPhone 5 only. I guess the problem is real but i could not see any useful information from these crash reports.

Crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: CE320831-76BF-4606-813F-9821F9C8B6C2
CrashReporter Key:   e41999cd7d4094ea7ac7b121345107dcebfa3e97
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             Ribony [946]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/91817EA6-9765-41B8-85BD-903928F6EFEE/Ribony.app/Ribony
Identifier:          com.impact.ribony
Version:             121 (5.1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.impact.ribony [593]


Date/Time:           2020-04-19 09:41:54.8309 +0300
Launch Time:         2020-04-19 09:41:50.0000 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.4 (14G61)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x168392e0
Termination Signal: Bus error: 10
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xa
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb90900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb906e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1d393be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1d392064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e51ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e4fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   GraphicsServices                0x1ea8fb40 GSEventRunModal + 80 (GSEvent.c:2245)
7   UIKit                           0x2266da52 UIApplicationMain + 150 (UIApplication.m:4089)
8   Ribony                          0x000280a0 main + 38 (ConversationModel.swift:18)
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x1cad24ea start + 2

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cba673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a744 _pthread_wqthread + 728 (pthread.c:2129)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cba673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   ???                             0x168392e0 0 + 377721568

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb90900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb906e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1d393be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1d392064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e51ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e4fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   Foundation                      0x1dc39af4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 258 (NSRunLoop.m:367)
7   Foundation                      0x1dc5676c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 86 (NSRunLoop.m:411)
8   UIKit                           0x22f6ead8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 128 (UIEventFetcher.m:313)
9   Foundation                      0x1dd1d8ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122 (NSThread.m:1163)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb93ba8 kevent + 24
1   Realm                           0x00a6930a realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 118
2   Realm                           0x00a69b20 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, st... + 112
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cba673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a744 _pthread_wqthread + 728 (pthread.c:2129)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb90900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb906e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   Ribony                          0x00175960 CLSMachExceptionServer + 900
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb90900 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cb906e0 mach_msg + 44 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1d393be2 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 144 (CFRunLoop.c:2527)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1d392064 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436 (CFRunLoop.c:2870)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e51ae CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470 (CFRunLoop.c:3113)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1d2e4fd0 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104 (CFRunLoop.c:3143)
6   CFNetwork                       0x1d9c2392 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 402 (NSURLConnection.mm:364)
7   Foundation                      0x1dd1d8ea __NSThread__start__ + 1122 (NSThread.m:1163)
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c93a _pthread_body + 216 (pthread.c:697)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5c85c _pthread_start + 234 (pthread.c:744)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a468 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:
Thread 13:
0   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x1ca5f62c ccn_sqr_ws + 168 (ccn_sqr.c:60)
1   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x1ca85b7c ccn_make_recip_newtonraphson + 374 (ccn_make_recip.c:142)
2   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x1ca85c80 ccn_make_recip + 60 (ccn_make_recip.c:201)
3   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x1ca84fb6 ccder_decode_rsa_pub + 72 (ccder_decode_rsa_pub.c:21)
4   libcorecrypto.dylib             0x1ca8531e ccrsa_import_pub + 30 (ccrsa_import_pub.c:16)
5   Security                        0x1d7b0d04 SecRSAPublicKeyInit + 108 (SecRSAKey.c:176)
6   Security                        0x1d79a198 SecKeyCreate + 106 (SecKey.c:493)
7   Security                        0x1d7b10f2 SecKeyCreateRSAPublicKey_ios + 28 (SecRSAKey.c:384)
8   Security                        0x1d78adf2 SecCertificateCopyPublicKey + 90 (SecCertificate.c:4814)
9   Security                        0x1d7b6564 __SecTrustCopyPublicKey_block_invoke + 24 (SecTrust.c:1411)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1cab1a34 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 50 (queue.c:3446)
11  Security                        0x1d7b64fe SecTrustCopyPublicKey + 92 (SecTrust.c:1402)
12  libcoretls_cfhelpers.dylib      0x371ef898 tls_helper_set_peer_pubkey + 62 (tls_helpers.c:199)
13  CFNetwork                       0x1da60c98 TCPIOConnection::_tlsProcessPublicKey(nw_tls_context*) + 12 (TCPIOConnection.cpp:3566)
14  CFNetwork                       0x1da5faa2 TCPIOConnection::_handleTLSEvent(nw_tls_context*, tls_handshake_message_t, void () block_pointer,... + 486 (TCPIOConnection.cpp:4363)
15  CFNetwork                       0x1da5f8b6 ___ZN15TCPIOConnection9_startTLSEv_block_invoke + 20 (TCPIOConnection.cpp:2668)
16  libnetwork.dylib                0x2879fd90 __tcp_connection_set_tls_message_handler_on_nw_connection_block_invoke + 126 (tcp_connection.m:1716)
17  libnetwork.dylib                0x287acdbe __nw_coretls_callback_handshake_message_block_invoke + 88 (protocol_coretls.c:776)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x1caa5796 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10 (init.c:963)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x1cab259c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 854 (inline_internal.h:2431)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x1caa8b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 886 (queue.c:4853)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x1cab41b4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 326 (inline_internal.h:2468)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1cab400e _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106 (queue.c:5550)
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a87c _pthread_wqthread + 1040 (pthread.c:2196)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cba673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x1cba673c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a8ea _pthread_wqthread + 1150 (pthread.c:2205)
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a45c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1cc5a454 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000004      r2: 0x00000003      r3: 0x192356d0
    r4: 0x33010005    r5: 0x39cfc048      r6: 0x39cf8000      r7: 0x00000001
    r8: 0x005c0000    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x015a9f68    sp: 0x19235570      lr: 0x00001200      pc: 0x168392e0
  cpsr: 0x60000010
```

As you can see Thread 4 is crashed. But this report looks like not symbolicated but actually it is symbolicated report. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: You can start using some crash reporting services, for example Firebase or AppCenter